# How to create a magazine app on iOS 9 and later?

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

Prior to iOS 9, the *proper* way to create a magazine app was to use the [NewsstandKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/newsstandkit) framework. However, with iOS 9, there have been some changes with the Newsstand and it looks like Newsstand is on its way to deprecation. The reasons for this thought of mine are:

1. On the [Newsstand](https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/) page itself, Apple News is endorsed for publishing content.
2. The Newsstand folder is removed on iOS 9.
3. There are no tutorials about Newsstand in Swift. Not in Apple's pages, not in RayWenderlich, not anywhere else.
4. Of the available [two](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/) [tutorials](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-make-a-magazine-app-in-ios-part-i/) about Newsstand (which are authored by the same author and in Objective-C), the author says that Newsstand is deprecated and new apps should not be developed using NewsstandKit. (The relevant [Disqus comment](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/#comment-2248413885) of author) However, the author does not tell how to develop magazine apps on iOS 9 or later.

So, my question is:

1. How should a magazine app be developed on iOS 9 or later?
2. What are the sources for developing magazine apps on iOS 9 or later?

Note that being able to make a magazine app *without* using Apple News is important, since Apple News is [available only on Australia, UK and US](https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#news) as of writing this.

Comment: I'm having the same question right now. Is NewsstandKit still the way to go?